# making an inset with PSTricks

Tags: pstricks, pst-plot

I have a main coordinate system, and inside this I would like to plot some data in an inset. Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=16pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-node, pst-coil, pst-plot}
\psset
{
    unit=0.1cm,
}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=false](0.0, -25)(108, 23.0)
\psaxes[Dx=10,Dy=10,linewidth=1pt, ticksize=2pt, Oy=-20]{->}(0.0,-20)(105,20)%THIS IS THE MAIN COORDINATE SYSTEM

%THIS IS MY DATA FOR THE INSET
\savedata{\mydata}[
{{0, 0}, {1., 0.946083}, {2., 1.60541}, {3., 1.84865}, {4., 1.7582},
{5., 1.54993}, {6., 1.42469}, {7., 1.4546}, {8., 1.57419},
{9., 1.66504}, {10., 1.65835}, {11., 1.57831}, {12., 1.50497},
{13., 1.49936}, {14., 1.55621}, {15., 1.61819}, {16., 1.6313},
{17., 1.59014}, {18., 1.53661}, {19., 1.51863}, {20., 1.54824}}]
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

The data I want to plot in an inset, which I would like to be able to move around freely inside the "main" coordinate system. Is there a smart way to do this in PSTricks?

EDIT: I sincerely apologize, but I forgot to note that the inset-plot should have *psaxes* including labels. This edit was made **after** Herbert's answer.

Comment: Please don't use graphics tag because it is irrelevant.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=16pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\psset{unit=0.1}
\begin{document}

\savedata{\mydata}[
{{0, 0}, {1., 0.946083}, {2., 1.60541}, {3., 1.84865}, {4., 1.7582},
{5., 1.54993}, {6., 1.42469}, {7., 1.4546}, {8., 1.57419},
{9., 1.66504}, {10., 1.65835}, {11., 1.57831}, {12., 1.50497},
{13., 1.49936}, {14., 1.55621}, {15., 1.61819}, {16., 1.6313},
{17., 1.59014}, {18., 1.53661}, {19., 1.51863}, {20., 1.54824}}]

\begin{pspicture}(-5, -25)(108, 23.0)
\psaxes[Dx=10,Dy=10,linewidth=1pt, ticksize=2pt, Oy=-20]{->}(0.0,-20)(105,20)%THIS IS THE MAIN COORDINATE SYSTEM
\listplot[linecolor=blue]{\mydata}
\rput(50,-10){\listplot[linecolor=red]{\mydata}}
\rput(70,10){\listplot[linecolor=green]{\mydata}}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

See also http://tug.org/PSTricks/main.cgi?file=pst-plot/fileplot
the first example shows a specific part of a data plot in another scaling.

If you need it together with a coordinate system then define an own command:

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=16pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\psset{unit=0.1}

\savedata{\mydata}[
{{0, 0}, {1., 0.946083}, {2., 1.60541}, {3., 1.84865}, {4., 1.7582},
{5., 1.54993}, {6., 1.42469}, {7., 1.4546}, {8., 1.57419},
{9., 1.66504}, {10., 1.65835}, {11., 1.57831}, {12., 1.50497},
{13., 1.49936}, {14., 1.55621}, {15., 1.61819}, {16., 1.6313},
{17., 1.59014}, {18., 1.53661}, {19., 1.51863}, {20., 1.54824}}]

\makeatletter
\def\myPlot{\@ifnextchar[\myPlot@i{\myPlot@i[]}}
\def\myPlot@i[#1](#2)#3#4{{%
  \rput[lb](#2){%
    \begin{pspicture}(0,0)(25,15)
    \listplot[#1]{#3}%
    \psaxes[Dx=10,Dy=10,linewidth=1pt,ticksize=2pt,linecolor=black,#4]{->}(0,0)(25,15)
  \end{pspicture}}%
}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(-5, -25)(108, 23.0)
\psaxes[Dx=10,Dy=10,linewidth=1pt, ticksize=2pt, Oy=-20]{->}(0.0,-20)(105,20)
\myPlot[linecolor=red](0,0){\mydata}{}
\myPlot[linecolor=red](50,-10){\mydata}{labelFontSize=\scriptscriptstyle}
\myPlot[linecolor=green](70,10){\mydata}{ticksize=-4pt 4pt
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I sincerely apologize, but I forgot to add in my OP that the inset-plot show have psaxes with labels. I will edit my OP.

Comment: see my enhanced answer. It has a second example

Comment: What if I want to be able to control the sizes of the ticklabels of the inset-plots independently of the main ticklabels? Let me know if I should create a new thread instead of asking here.. seems relevant to continue here

Comment: then add another argument for `\psaxes`, eg `\myPlot[linecolor=red](50,-10){parameter for \psaxes}{\mydata}`

Comment: But the command for axes-label size is long and complicated, you showed it here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/137018/changing-intersection-between-axes-in-pstricks/137019?noredirect=1#137019. Can I insert those 5 lines in {....}?

Comment: that was only for the rotation of the labels. Without that it is simple and only a new argument.

Comment: Adding `labelFontSize=\footnotesize` to `\psaxis[..]` in the `\makeatletter`-macro doesn't do anything?! Also tried with `scriptscriptstyle`, still no effect

Comment: see my edited answer for the second example. The syntax is now `\myPlot[...](70,10){\mydata}{options for the axis}`. I didn't uploaded a new image!

Comment: Ahh, the rotate-macro in the other thread overrides the individual ticklabel-size. Is there a way to circumvent this?

Comment: As an alternative, I can always make the inset in a separate .EPS file and include it manually...

Comment: sure! Hold the definition for the rotation lokal

Comment: Sorry for all the question, but there's a final one: Is it possible to change the `psset{unit}` for the inline plot? E.g., such that the main coordinate system along x runs from 0..100 in 10 cm, but the inset runs from -40..40 in 2/3/.. cm? Let me know if I need a new thread for this question

Comment: In the inset macro you can set everything. It should already local.